# If I respawn a boss and kill him with Lucatiel again, does that count towards the 3 bossfight requirement to prevent her from disappearing?

Tags: dark-souls-2

I've killed the Lost Sinner with Lucatiel more than 3 times by respawning with a bonfire ascetic.   Have I met the requirement to prevent Lucatiel of Mirrahh from disappearing after Aldia's Keep?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep - any boss kills in a single playthrough (ascetic or not) will count.

Comment: This counts for Benhart as well.